# Why aren't badges paginated?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

What is the current reasoning for the badge routes not being paged? Badges (/tags) is probably the current longest route, and it is annoying that this route isn't paginated, but stackauth/sites is. Should it not be the other way around (unless I am missing something obvious)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were't paginated due to their essentially static nature.

This has since been determined to be a mistake, they're slated to be redone in a subsequent API version.

Comment: great, something to look forward to recoding :/ And the sites method isn't [roughly] equally static?

Comment: @Jonathan: The sites method is obviously not static by nature (in the sense that it changes frequently).

Comment: Sites route is quite static, we are told it must be called no more than once a day at minimum, and compared to questions it's very static. But there is no case when you'd only download the first page of sites.